# biblatex: inherit shorthand

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

*UPDATED MWE*

I want to cite articles from an encyclopedia, with using the shorthand of the encyclopedia:
Like

> Lastname, Firstname. Art. *articltitle*. In: NG, Vol. 11, pp. 30–40, p. 35.

I want to use this in the cites as in the bibliography.

My code so far (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvreference{NG,
title={The new Grove dictionary of music and musicians},
editor={Stanley Sadie},%begr. von Grove, George
year={1980},
volumes={20},
shorthand={NG}
}

@reference{NG-BD11,
crossref={NG},
title={Lindeman - Mean-tone},
volume={11},
year={1980},
location={London},
publisher={Macmillan}
}

@inreference{author-NG-ML,
crossref={NG-BD11},
author={Firstname Lastname},
title={articletitle},
pages={30--40}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%what to print out?
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printtext{Art.}%added
  \newunit%added
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{%added
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}}%
    {\printfield{mainshorthand}}%added, here I want the shorthand from the mvreference (NG)
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\noindent{}The author wrote something about my subject.\autocite[35]{author-NG-ML}
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[nottype=mvreference, nottype=reference]
\end{document}
```

Output:

> Lastname, Firstname. Art. *articletitle*. In: *The new Grove dictionary of music
>   and musicians*. Vol. 11: *Lindeman - Mean-tone*. Ed. by Stanley Sadie. 20 vols.
>   London: Macmillan, 1980, pp. 30–40.

I've experimented with the command `\DeclareDataInheritance`, to inherit the shorthand, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: For suppressing the page field in citations with a postnote, see [The `verbose-ibid` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/71-style-verbose-ibid.pdf), have a look at the `citepages` option, you probably want `citepages=suppress` or `citepages=omit`.

Comment: I just noticed that your `\DeclareDataInheritance` is from a `mvreference` to a `reference` but your example contains a `mvreference` and an `inreference`. So naturally the `\noinherit` rules you have specified there will not apply. Furthermore the field `mainshorthand` does not exist so you will have trouble using it (you could define it in a custom data model though). It also seems strange to me that you specify the `pages` (5-35) in the `inreference` and then claim to want to suppress that.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But shouldn't it be suppressed, too, if it's not inherited? (`\noinherit{pages}`) That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: No the `inreference` has a `pages` field on its own - it does not inherit any page information: they are already there. `noinherit` means just that - the information will not be inherited from a "parent" crossref - it does not mean that information present in the actual entry will be suppressed - why would it?

Comment: As an aside: In your example `mylexikon` does not really seem to be a `mvreference`, it just seems to be an ordinary `reference`. I also find it very odd to include particular entries from a reference in the bibliography. (Say, if you had looked up all of King Henry VIII's wifes would you have an entry for all of those articles in the bibliography? I think it is much more reasonable to give a citation of say "Encyclopaedia of English King's Wifes: Anne Boleyn" and just cite the "Encyclopaedia of English King's Wifes" in the bibliography.)

Comment: Sorry, I've mixed up a few things. I've updated the MWE. The problems remain!

Comment: Mhhh, normally a `mvreference` would refer to one reference work like say "The Encyclopædia Britannica, 15th edition" or "Brockhaus Enzyklopädie", the `pages` field does not make a lot of sense there. Then `reference` would refer to say "Encyclopædia Britannica, volume 4: Ca to De", while `inreference` would be the entry about "Cato". So one would only expect the `inreference` to have a pages field.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. Thank you for your explanation about the different reference-types. My encyclo IS in fact a MV-encyclo. I just don't provide all informations, and maybe put some in the wrong place because it's not really part of my problem. In fact my MVreference has a shorthand (encyclo title), my reference of course not (A-C), and my article needs to refer to the shorthand of the MVreference and has the pages-information: Art. _Ships_. In: Lexikon, Vol. 3, H-K, pp. 350-360. But this just makes the problem more complex IMO.

Comment: I've updated the MWE and it works now to suppress the inheritance of year and pages (as it should). But I can't force biblatex to inherit the shorthand. This is my question.
If I understand it right, the command `\inherit{shorthand}{mainshorthand}`, should "create" the new field "mainshorthand" and fill it with the content of the MVreference-shorthand. Or is this wrong?

Comment: It might make the problem a little more complex but greatly helps to understand what you want to achieve and how to get there. Would you mind awfully to bring the MWE closer to your actual problem?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to have a pages field for the `@inreference` `myarticle` in the bibliography?

Comment: I'm working on a "real life" example

Comment: It's online, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly looks clearer now, I will investigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution might be quite specific to your needs.

As mentioned in the comments, it is probably best to have a `mainshorthand` for the `inreference` that can be inherited from the `mvreference`.

This is done via a custom data model file called `refinherit.dbx`, you will have to place this file somewhere LaTeX can find it.

```
\ProvidesFile{refinherit.dbx}[2014/04/03]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{mainshorthand}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mainshorthand}
\endinput
```

In the MWE below this is achieved with `filecontents`, obviously you will have the file in an appropriate place in your actual use case.

We load this datamodel via the `datamodel` option

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, datamodel=refinherit]{biblatex}
```

We then declare the inheritance

```
\DeclareDataInheritance{mvreference}{inreference,reference}{%
  \inherit{shorthand}{mainshorthand}
  \noinherit{volumes}
}
```

That is, `mvreference`'s `shorthand` becomes `inreference`'s `mainshorthand`

Finally, we modify the `inreference` driver to omit some information and print the `mainshorthand` instead if that is available

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printtext{Art.}%added
  \newunit%added
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{mainshorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{edition}}%
    {\printfield{mainshorthand}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{part}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{mainshorthand}
    {\printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refinherit.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{refinherit.dbx}[2014/04/03]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{mainshorthand}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mainshorthand}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, datamodel=refinherit]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mvreference{NG,
  title       = {The new Grove dictionary of music and musicians},
  editor      = {Stanley Sadie},
  editora     = {Grove, George},
  editoratype = {founder},
  year        = {1980},
  volumes     = {20},
  shorthand   = {NG},
  location    = {London},
  publisher   = {Macmillan},
}

@reference{NG-BD11,
  crossref  = {NG},
  title     = {Lindeman -- Mean-tone},
  volume    = {11},
  year      = {1980},
}

@inreference{author-NG-ML,
  crossref  = {NG-BD11},
  author    = {Arnold Uthor},
  title     = {Firstname Lastname},
  pages     = {30--40},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDataInheritance{mvreference}{inreference,reference}{%
  \inherit{shorthand}{mainshorthand}
  \noinherit{volumes}
}

%what to print out?
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printtext{Art.}%added
  \newunit%added
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{mainshorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{edition}}%
    {\printfield{mainshorthand}}
  \newunit
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{part}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{mainshorthand}
    {\printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\noindent{}The author wrote something about my subject.\autocite[35]{author-NG-ML}
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[nottype=mvreference, nottype=reference]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solutions is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! Also thx for the editora-field :) Still a lot to learn.. And sorry for the confusion. Just one thing, I think the `dbx-filecontent` must stand before biblatex is included, or you don't get the right result.

Comment: @musicman Yes, the `.dbx` file has to be present in order for `biblatex` to work, in the MWE the file should therefore have been created before loading `biblatex`. In a normal document though, that should be no problem since you would not create `refinherit.dbx` via `filecontents`, but create it and save it somewhere LaTeX can find it.